# Can not compile ROS 2: CMake Error: INSTALL(EXPORT) given unknown export "HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET"

Tags: ros, ros2, build, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I follow the instructions at https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup. I would want to have ardent on xenial, but the setup fails at

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
```

The output ends with

```
...
Finished <<< python_cmake_module [1.90s]
Starting >>> gmock_vendor
Finished <<< ament_cmake_ros [1.77s]                                                                                                  
Starting >>> rosidl_generator_c
Finished <<< gmock_vendor [2.45s]                                                                                                           
Starting >>> launch_testing
--- stderr: ament_index_cpp                                                                                                           
CMake Error: INSTALL(EXPORT) given unknown export "HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET"
---
Failed   <<< ament_index_cpp    [ Exited with code 1 ]
Aborted  <<< rosidl_generator_c
Aborted  <<< fastrtps
Aborted  <<< launch_testing

Summary: 52 packages finished [1min 13s]
  1 package failed: ament_index_cpp
  3 packages aborted: fastrtps launch_testing rosidl_generator_c
  1 package had stderr output: ament_index_cpp
  133 packages not processed
```

I sourced the following before:

```
source /opt/ros/ardent/setup.bash
source /opt/rti.com/rti_connext_dds-5.3.1/setenv_ros2rti.bash
```

Can something be done with that? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302360/can-not-compile-ros-2:-cmake-error:-install(export)-given-unknown-export-%22has_library_target%22/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-04**:
I would suspect you are using an outdated version of the `ament_cmake` repository. Can you share the hash of your cloned repository?

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-04**:
Dirk, see an update in the question, thanks.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-04**:
If updating the source to the latest master solved the problem for you please post that as an answer and accept that answer. So future readers can find it. The new problem sounds very different and probably warrants a separate question (since it is not related to the title).

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-05**:
No it does not - the build is parallel and asynchronous, sometimes the same error shows up also with master. All in all, I could not compile any of the two versions.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-05**:
If you experience non-determinism please post the exact steps you perform as well as full logs from both invocations (the one with the failure and the one without).

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-05**:
I wil  upgrade my OS, try Bouncy and post. I guess that the nondeterminism comes from two errors, whichever comes first is caused by the relative speed of threads in a parallel compilation.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-05**:
You can process packages sequentially with `--executor sequential` and debug / report one problem at at time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution which worked for me is [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/302458/any-chance-of-compiling-ros-2-from-sources-now/?answer=302588#post-id-302588).

---

Originally posted by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) with karma: 118 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0